# Delete row from 2 related tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 tables in my database (Echipa, and Staff) that are connection with an relationship.
[image]

To add a row in my tables I just add in the first one, then in the second

```
private void AddElement(string nume, string an, string tara, string antrenor, string presedinte, string actionar)
{
    conexiune.Open();
    Comanda comanda = new Comanda("insert into echipa values( @nume, @an,@tara)", conexiune);
    comanda.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nume", nume));
    comanda.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@an", an));
    comanda.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tara", tara));
    comanda.ExecuteNonQuery();


    comanda = new Comanda("insert into staff values( @antrenor,@presedinte,@actionar)", conexiune);
    comanda.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@antrenor", antrenor));
    comanda.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@presedinte", presedinte));
    comanda.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@actionar", actionar));
    comanda.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conexiune.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Succes");
}
```

But what if I want to delete a row for update a row from both?
How should I do?

I don't know why but I can't even delete from 1 table

```
private void DeleteElement(string nume)
{
    conexiune.Open();
    Comanda comanda = new Comanda("delete from echipa where 'nume'=@nume", conexiune);
    comanda.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nume", nume));

    comanda.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conexiune.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Succes");
}
```

This won't do nothing to my tables..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

I got 2 tables
Echipa - that has EID (int) as primary key and autonumber
Staff - that has SID (int) is just autonumber

First i have to delete the row from staff and then from Echipa and it works !
Somewhere up i got using Comanda=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand , is easier for me) and is in my language)

```
 private void StergeElement(string nume)
    {
        conexiune.Open();


        Comanda comanda = new Comanda("delete from staff where SID=@ID", conexiune);
        comanda.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", nume));

        comanda.ExecuteNonQuery();

         comanda = new Comanda("delete from echipa where EID=@ID", conexiune);
        comanda.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", nume));

        comanda.ExecuteNonQuery();



        conexiune.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Succes");
    }
```

Thanks to @apomene for the answer , it helped me a little!

Answer (score 3):

Best way to do that is to setup cascading deletes on the foreign key between the two tables. this way when you delete rows from the master table, all child rows from the second table will be deleted automatically.

Comment: This is the way I would approach it too.  Alternatively, OP could issue two deletes, but make sure they delete the child before the parent, preferably in a transaction.

Comment: Can you please provide some code or links to some example ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Define the columns after "echipa".

```
conexiune.Open();
    Comanda comanda = new Comanda("insert into echipa(nume, an, tara) values( @nume, @an,@tara)", conexiune);
    comanda.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nume", nume));
    comanda.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@an", an));
    comanda.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tara", tara));
    comanda.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I want to delete a row from both of the tables, i showed how I've added my elements into the tables and that works, I don't know how to delete or update them...If i delete from one i get the error The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Staff_Echipa". The conflict occurred in database "..

Answer (score 1):

If no deletes are been made,( I guess your field name is `nume`) you just have to remove quotes:

```
Comanda comanda = new Comanda("delete from echipa where nume=@nume", conexiune);
        comanda.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nume", nume));

        comanda.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Yea I was wrong there, but I can't delete it because is connected to the second database and i get the error The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Staff_Echipa". The conflict occurred in database "